# Что такое Application life cycle в контексте WP?

Tags: wordpress

Может кто-то объяснить или указать пример что такое WP Application life cycle ?

Comment: [жизненный цикл системы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Жизненный_цикл_системы) вообще и [программного обеспечения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Жизненный_цикл_программного_обеспечения) в частности.

Comment: А как именно это сопоставимо к WordPress ?

Comment: точно так же, как и к любому другому программному обеспечению.